# EE3 Control Panel Theme

Tags: control-panel, ee3, cp-themes

I used a customised control panel theme for my EE2 websites. Does anyone know how I would go about creating a custom theme stylesheet for EE3?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE3 does not support custom control panel themes. You can add custom CSS and javascript using extension hooks (or an add-on [like this one](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/digi-nut-control-panel-css-js)), but there is no support for having multiple CP themes and switching between them.

Comment: Your suggested add-on works a treat Derek, but do you know if there's a way to style the login screen as I think the add-on only styles the control panel once logged in?

Comment: Not without hacking the core files, nope.

Comment: @TomPerkins My add-on 'Veto' allows you to style the login screen: http://dvt.ee/veto